# Cannot find proper function call

Tags: javascript, amp-html

I am building an AMP form with a button to invoke my function and I get the following error:

```
[Action] Target (SCRIPT) doesn't support "send" action.​​​ <button class="button i-amphtml-error" on="tap:quoteFormScript.send">
```

According to the documentation the call to a function should be:

```
eventName:targetId[.methodName[(arg1=value, arg2=value)]]
```

This my code with relative and full path to target(both fail):

```
<form action-xhr="https://example.com/quote" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" id="quoteForm">
<form action-xhr="/quote" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" id="quoteForm">
<button on = "tap:quoteFormScript.send" class="button">Send</button>
</form>

<script id="quoteFormScript" type="text/plain" target="amp-script">
function send(){
   alert("Send");
}
</script>
```

I have tried:

```
<button on = "tap:quoteFormScript.send" class="button">Send</button>
<button on = "tap:quoteFormScript.send()" class="button">Send</button>
```

Any ideas?